# How to make UICell clickable in SWIFT like in recents calls in iPhone?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I want to click on the cells in UItableView and then make an action in the same view. (NO NEED ANOTHER CONTROLLER APPEAR)
for example, if you go to the recents calls in your iPhone and click on any name the phone will make a call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the UITableView reference, specifically the section on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

You can handle the tap in there or call any function you like.